# Beginning Spring, "Application failed to start with classpath", "Error starting Tomcat context", and other errors

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've just started doing the Spring tutorial in the documentation (the first one - [react-and-spring-data-rest](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/), using a basic `Employee` class) and have a printout that I'm almost reluctance to paste, due to how large it is.

The project skeleton was generated by the **spring-initializer** and I'm running in **IntelliJ**.

Here's that `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0         
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

It's hard to keep track, so I'll print the first part with an error after the server starts running.

```
2016-02-18 14:25:38.050  INFO 13272 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-02-18 14:25:38.055  INFO 13272 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-02-18 14:25:38.057  INFO 13272 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-02-18 14:25:38.300  INFO 13272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-02-18 14:25:38.402  INFO 13272 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2016-02-18 14:25:38.597 ERROR 13272 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
2016-02-18 14:25:38.632  WARN 13272 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2016-02-18 14:25:38.660 ERROR 13272 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
```

Nearing "build Hibernate session factory":

```
.... (stacktrace omitted for length)...


nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10db5cd': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#10db5cd' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10db5cd': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:233) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:181) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAsRegistrationBean(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:176) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addAdaptableBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:79) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:237) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.selfInitialize(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:224) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.access$000(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:85) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext$1.onStartup(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:209) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter.onStartup(TomcatStarter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar:1.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: : Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#10db5cd' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10db5cd': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#10db5cd' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10db5cd': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: : Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#10db5cd' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#10db5cd': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
```

...

Comment: Is that all the stacktrace you got? Add more if you have more.

Comment: When I run it in Maven, I get enough that exceeds the post size limit, which is why I only printed the part from right up to where the server boots. When I flag it with -e to view the full stack trace, I get an output of several hundred thousand characters (still don't understand Spring).
Do you have any inclinations about what to look for, so I could copy and paste what's around it?

Comment: Run the `public static void main(...) { ... }`  with Intellij and put the console log here.

Comment: With what I said, earlier:
"too long by 119392 characters" shows up below the comment box.

I'll start putting more after "startup failed", but it won't fit it all.

Comment: Last part of stacktrace says `Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory` which usually means some persistence layer problems. Prolly problem with database connection or wrong entity mapping. Post us stacktrace past that part

Comment: Thanks,kamil.
I've queued up the stack trace near Hibernate SessionFactory and pasted more starting from that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally figured it out.

The `@Id` annotation in the tutorial was supposed to be imported from `javax.persistence`, and, because it was a spring tutorial, I'd carelessly imported it with IntelliJ from `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id`, so it looked the same, with a different import statement.

Several things I caught in the output: `No identifier specified for entity:` 
Then, after running in debug mode, I somehow came up with a `ClassNotFoundException` from the main class, which, through SpringApplication.run() calls itself...and could not find...itself.
Ran me around it circles, but I eventually got the careless mistake.